# Cross-reference a section inside a field in a table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, reactable, ktable

Is it possible to cross-reference a section inside a field in a table with omething like the following?

```
# using "asis" results
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c("\@ref(some-section-id)")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
kableExtra::kable(df,
      format = "markdown")
```

When I tried the above code, it says

> Error: '@' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""@"

Comment: If you want a backslash in your string you need to escape it : `c("\\@ref(some-section-id)")`